# how to write cursor alternative query in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I need to implement without using cursor. below script is using cursor and it's taking 5 hours for 140k records.
How to improve the performance in sql server?

in the orginal table have over 100k records.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

CREATE TABLE #temp (
RecordID int identity,
Address varchar(50),
City varchar(30),
State varchar(5),
GPSLat numeric(9,6),
GPSLong numeric(9,6),
MapURL varchar(255))

INSERT INTO #temp (Address, City, State)
VALUES ('1033 Southwest 152nd Street', 'Burien', 'WA')

INSERT INTO #temp (Address, City, State)
VALUES ('11910 Northeast 154th Street', 'Brush Prairie', 'WA')

INSERT INTO #temp (Address, City, State)
VALUES ('500 SeaWorld Drive', 'San Diego', 'CA')

INSERT INTO #temp (Address, City, State)
VALUES ('1 Legoland Drive', 'Carlsbad', 'CA')


DECLARE curGeo CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FOR
SELECT RecordID, Address, City, State
FROM #temp

DECLARE @RecordID int
DECLARE @Address varchar(50)
DECLARE @City varchar(30)
DECLARE @State varchar(5)
DECLARE @GPSLatitude numeric(9, 6)
DECLARE @GPSLongitude numeric(9, 6)
DECLARE @MapURL varchar(255)

OPEN curGeo

FETCH curGeo INTO
    @RecordID,
    @Address,
    @City,
    @State

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC opsstream.sputilGeocode
            @Address = @Address OUTPUT,
            @City = @City OUTPUT,
            @State = @State OUTPUT,
            @GPSLatitude = @GPSLatitude OUTPUT,
            @GPSLongitude = @GPSLongitude OUTPUT,
            @MapURL = @MapURL OUTPUT


        UPDATE #temp
        SET
        GPSLat = @GPSLatitude,
        GPSLong = @GPSLongitude,
        MapURL = @MapURL
        WHERE
        RecordID = @RecordID

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT 'Warning: RecordID ' + CAST(@RecordID AS varchar(100)) + ' could not be geocoded.' 
    END CATCH


    FETCH curGeo INTO
        @RecordID,
        @Address,
        @City,
        @State
END

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Comment: To get rid of the cursor, you'll first have to create a version of opsstream.sputilGeocode that's capable of processing all addresses in your table at once, rather than one at a time. The use of a table valued parameter can help in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

You have a procedure call in your code, so I'm quite sure the problem is not the cursor, but the row-by-row logic done with the procedure. You might improve the performance of the cursor by defining it as `fast_forward`, but that might not be noticeable.

You have a procedure that you call, so either you need to change the procedure to accept a [table valued parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.100).aspx), and then of course change your procedure so that it's not a row-by-row operation or change it to a table valued function, but if you use the multi statement one, it's probably not going to improve your performance.